# Boot and early boot, mounting befor mount command available

Tags: mount, boot

I would like to know, what files are required before the `mount` command is available (early boot).

Basically I am asking this because I observed that mounting at startup (with `/etc/fstab`) is not really done at startup. One way for me to discover that has been to crash the system while moving `/usr` to a mounted-at-startup disk and symlink it to `/`.  Mounting failed because command was on mounted drive (Assumption).

I've noticed that my `/` directory is mounted (Do not know if is the right term) way before the other disks (not mentioning boot and recovery btw).

Regarding whether it is possible or not I would like to automatically mount a disk (like `/dev/sda1`) without having to wait for `/usr` binaries.

Not to mention I am very curious and not afraid of diving into the computer (as far as I understand what I am doing).

Comment: There is a very tiny mini linux system -called initramfs-, which contains the `mount` command, located in `/boot/init*/`. The kernel loads this filesystem to ram directly after boot, and this initrd will mount the real root filesystem (and the rest).

Comment: Well thanks, that is exactly the type of information I was looking for. Do you know if any type of command are executed after mounting root ? (type of command that would be located in ```/sbin``` for instance). I will look more into this ram file system procedure :)

Comment: You can find all scripts which are in initrd located in `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/` and `/etc/initramfs-tools` on Debian based systems. On other distribution they're located in a similar folder.